# What's the most efficient way to deal with 20+ different static layouts?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

Right now I'm making an app that requires me to have about 20 or more different pages/layouts, one loaded at a time, but little/no intercommunication between them. They would be very static. Right now I had the idea to have one activity, one fragment that would inflate a different layout in the onCreateView, and the fragment would be reloaded everytime the user selected another page. However I just realized that wouldn't work at all because I can't put the return statement of onCreateView in an if statement, and no workaround work.

So now I don't know the most efficient way to do this. There's no way having 20+ layouts and 20+ classes, one for each page is ideal. It seems very redundant.

Comment: May I ask why you have so many different layouts? Are these all different screens the user can view? Is there any similarities among any of these layouts that can be utilized?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice 20 isn't that many.  If you're in any non trivial app you'll have at least that many

Comment: @GabeSechan I guess all my apps so far have been pretty trivial ;-(  Still, I think my follow-on questions are still valid.

Comment: They are information pages about different topics (think mobile wikipedia layout). For simplicity sake and for flexibility, I find it better to have different layout files for each page, instead of a single layout that can't be modified easily

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Fragment's bundle to communicate to it which layout to use.
In the Fragment class, create a static method to create the Fragment instance and set it's bundle, for example:

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(int layoutId) {
        MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("layoutId", layoutId); // e.g. layoutId = R.layout.layout_fragment_01
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }
```

and then in the fragment's onCreateView, get the layout id from the bundle:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(getArguments().getInt("layoutId", 0), container, false);
}
```

then, in your Activity, you'd do something like the following:

```
MyFragment fragment = MyFragment.newInstance(R.layout.fragment_layout_01);
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();
```